# Scala method execution Order in Pattern Matching and if-else

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have some experience in Java programming but recently turn to Scala. When using intellij idea to debug the project, some situation make me confusing:

```
  def test(): String = {

    var exp = Some("a");
    var x = 20;
    var y = 10;

    exp match {
      case e@Some("a") => "match a"
      case e@Some(_) => {
        val empty: ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer.empty
        if (empty.isEmpty) {
          "match other and empty arr"
        }
        else {
          if (empty.size > 1) {
            " arr size > 1"
          }
          else {
            " bad "
          }
        }
      }

      case _ => "match nothing"
    }
  }
```

normally the method test will be terminated at line 12 and return String "match other and empty arr", and It return that. However, the program will execute to line 19 immediately after line 12 (according to the calling stack in the "debugger" window) which bring some trouble when reading the  source code. what is the problem and why it happens ? thanks a  lot!

UPDATE:
the Screenshot that I truly meet the question in project, I doubt that line 247 is never be reached but the running stack shows that the program executed at line 247, which is impossible because it will return at line 241, besides the local variable cannot be reached, which  also wired if the program is still executed in current method.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked what your function actually returns? With like `println(test())`

Comment: @marstran Yes. Apparently it will return the correct result, but the  execution order is  sort of incomprehensible

Comment: What you see in the debugger might now always been accurate. Keep in mind that it's not always possible to match compiled code to source code precisely.

Comment: I would say that this is just a bug in the **Intellij** debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code in an online worksheet [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/18lwqrRcRAO3k82im13nXA/1) and it behaves [as documented](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/control-structures.html#match-expressions):

> the cases are considered in the order they are written

Since `exp` is `Some("a")` the expression corresponding to the first case (`case e@Some("a") => "match a"`) will be evaluated.

Notice that unlike Java's `switch` statement, there's no fall-through (just like in the recently introduced `switch` *expression*, available since Java 17 -- see here).

Comment: It run correctly on my  pc as well, but it is just a simplify demo, when I debug the project team and currently working. It hehave as what I described on the theme. I have update the screenshot.

Comment: I copied your code in an empty project in IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-231.9161.38, built on June 20, 2023 -- I set a breakpoint on the line with `exp match`. I ran the code in debug mode and pressed `Step Into`. I got to the line with `case e@Some("a") => "match a"`. I pressed `Step Into` again. The program terminated. Not sure what you're experiencing. Maybe you're on a different version of IntelliJ and there's a bug in the debugger for Scala?